# MySQL conditional SELECT & calculate values based on condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table, with the structure:

```
date (DATE)
time (TIME)
quantity_ok (INT)
quantity_ng (INT)
shift (INT)
target (DECIMAL)
```

It contains production data for a given prod line. The catch in this is, that the shift doesn't change at 00:00:00, but at 23:00:00 (3 shifts, 07-15, 15-23, 23-07).

In this table I already have the "correct" dates for the given shift (today's production between 00:00:00 - 07:00:00 has the date of yesterday, as it belongs to yesterday's 3rd shift).

I have to calculate the actual % of the target, based on the idea:

`(SUM(Quality_ok) for given shift) / (nr. of min. from the beginning of the shift)*target`

What I am doing is this:

```
SELECT
`date`,
SUM(quantity_ok) AS `SUM(quantity_ok)`,
(TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:00:00'))/60*`target` AS actual_target,
SUM(quantity_ok)/((TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:00:00'))/60*`target`)*100    AS `Actual % of target`,
`time`
FROM U126_td
WHERE (`date` = CURDATE())
```

The above works for the 1st shift correctly, for the second shift it gives a summed actual percentage (I would need it to reset to zero from 15:00), and it gives no result for 00:00-07:00.

I should calculate based on shifts conditionally, but here I'm lost.

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT 2:
Since i came up with something that seems to work:

```
SELECT
`date`, `time`, `actshift`,
SUM(quantity_ok) AS `SUM(quantity_ok)`,
MAX(shift) AS `MAX(shift)`,
MAX(`time`) AS `MAX(time)`,
CASE actshift WHEN  1 THEN
SUM(quantity_ok)/((TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:00:00'))/60*`target`)*100 
          WHEN  2 THEN
SUM(quantity_ok)/((TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC('15:00:00'))/60*`target`)*100
                        WHEN  3 THEN
                                        CASE MAX(`time`) WHEN MAX(`time`)<'07:00:00' THEN
                                            SUM(quantity_ok)/((TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC('00:00:00'))/60*`target`)*100
                                                                        ELSE
                                            SUM(quantity_ok)/((TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC('23:00:00'))/60*`target`)*100
                                        END
END  AS `Actual % of target`
FROM U126_td
WHERE (`date` = CURDATE())
```

Of course, all this shi(f)t needs to be cleaned a "bit" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd need some sample data and desired output to come up with a complete query design, but essentially you don't need to calculate the start of the shift or even which shift you are in to work out how long it is since the start of the shift.

You simply need to add one hour to the time value in question to deal with the offset from midnight, then work out the remainder after dividing by the length of the shift.

```
-- How many seconds have passed since the current shift started?
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR) % 28800;
-- Or in minutes:
SELECT FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR) / 60) % 480;
```

Comment: Hi Matt Here you have my actual table, as of 07:04:00, 2016-06-14. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4B9GxnbFt6UVG8wNE5iT0IyX00/view?usp=sharing) The table is updated every minute, with the prod. data. I need the actual % of target to be returned, every time the query runs.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I don't understand the final requirements at all. Perhaps you could edit the question to include the desired output for your sample data?

Comment: Hi The final requirement is only one number (percentage), wich is recalculated every time the query runs. The table data is updated once/min with data from sensors (quantity_ok, quantity_ng). Anyway, i think i solved it: I insert a column at the end, with the actual shift nr: `code` IF(HOUR(NOW())>=7 AND HOUR(NOW())<15, 1, ( IF(HOUR(NOW())>=15 AND HOUR(NOW())<23, 2, 3)))